# Iphone Core Data: Date Default Value as Current date

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

Im using Core data. I have an entity with an attribute of type Date. Is there a way I can set Default Values as Current Date? (Like entering 'CURRENTDATE' or something in default value of the attribute?)

Thanks

Answer (score 34):

You could use "now" in the model, but Core Data evaluates that at compile time, not runtime.  You'll get the date of compilation stored in your model defaults, which is probably not what you want:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/07/core-data-default-dates-in-data-model.html

The most reliable way to ensure a default property value of the current date is to override `-awakeFromInsert` in an NSManagedObject subclass and assign the current date there.

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert 
{
   [super awakeFromInsert];
   self.date = [NSDate date];
   // or [self setPrimitiveDate:[NSDate date]]; 
   // to avoid triggering KVO notifications

}
```

Note: If you're making use of nested managed object contexts (or UIManagedDocument), the above will not work as expected. This advice only applies when using single managed object contexts.

Comment: This isn't right because awakeForInsert will be called every time a NSManagedObject will be created. Different NSManagedObject can be created in different threads while they represent the same CoreData entity.

Comment: Creating a managed object in two different threads that represent the same entity would violate the laws of Core Data physics. And definitely be an indicator of some app logic error. Doing something like this is not a recommended practice.

Comment: I believe you can. Here is a fair use case: you could definitely have a Core Data object on the main thread for display (let's say a "Photo" object) and then have a worker thread in the background loading up the same object from the database, applying some image processing, saving the photo back to the persistent store. At that point you get a global change notification and the main thread can decide to merge the changes into the main thread managed object context.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of the managed object lifecycle at play here. `-awakeFromInsert:` is only ever invoked when a managed object is newly created and inserted into a persistent store. If you create a Photo object that represents a given photo in your app, you'll logically only insert that object into the database once. You might fetch it multiple times, but `-awakeFromInsert:` is not involved at all in the workflow of a managed object fetch.  The use case you describe is vague with respect to Photo object creation versus fetching.

Comment: I believe you're being mislead by the method name. From the documentation: `awakeFromInsert: Invoked automatically by the Core Data framework when the receiver is first inserted into a ***managed object context***.` Searching a bit more on the web, I also find this link talking about this gotcha, awakeFromInsert is called when the NSManagedObject is first inserted in the context, not the store: http://www.mikeabdullah.net/an--awakefrominsert-gotcha.html

Comment: I see now. The interaction of parent-child contexts adds a twist to the use of `awakeFromInsert`. I stand corrected. Thanks for Abdullah reference. If I'd read it before, I'd forgotten it.